# What's a good item card to get water energy out of a deck in pokemon?

Tags: pokemon

[image]

I'm trying to make a deck for my Blastoise but I can't find/figure out what good item /pokemon card to draw water energy from my deck. This is my main card.

Comment: This Blastoise isn't standard legal in the pokemon tcg, if you don't care about that then use the base set professor oak and bill which are the strongest draw engine.  In any case you will want items that draw you extra cards and energy retrieval cards.  There have been a few good Blastoise decks over the years that have deck list posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your deck, there's nothing I can think of specific to water.  You have [Energy Spinner](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Energy_Spinner_(Unbroken_Bonds_170)) and similar cards that get any energy, though, but not enough to make that card all that powerful.

Blastoise though, if you're going to play him, you might as well play [Team Up Blastoise](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Blastoise_(Team_Up_25)):

> Once during your turn (before your attack), you may look at the top 6 cards of your deck and attach any number of Water Energy cards you find there to your Pokémon in any way you like. Shuffle the other cards back into your deck.

That's realistically a better version of the above card, and is standard-legal.